# React Jest/React-testing-Library route change not working properly

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have been trying to record URL changes on click of anchor tag. While this works on the actual page, it doesn't when I write tests in Jest.

Here's the code:

```js
import { renderApp } from "<src>/tests/util";
import { fireEvent, wait } from "react-testing-library";

import {
  getLocationAPath,
  getLocationBPath,
  getLocationCPath
} from "<src>/paths";

let getByDataQa;
let history;

beforeEach(() => {
  ({ getByDataQa, history } = renderApp(getLocationAPath(), {}));
});

test("Validate if routes work", async () => {
  let routePath;
  fireEvent.click(getByDataQa("Container.locB"));
  //await wait();
  routePath = getLocationBPath();
  expect(history.location.pathname).toEqual(routePath);

  fireEvent.click(getByDataQa("Container.locC"));
  routePath = getLocationCPath();
  console.log(history.location.pathname);
  expect(history.location.pathname).toEqual(routePath);

});
```

Comment: Can you include the code of `renderApp`?

Comment: <li>
    <a
       href={getLocationBPath()}
        className={classNames(styles.bar)}
      data-qa="foo"
        title="xyz"
      /> </li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced `anchors` with `href` to `Link`s. That solved the issue.